# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySql host

Tags: c#, mysql, database, xampp

//this is my code to connect to the database (xampp)

```
private void runQuery()
{
    String ConnectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDatabase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;";

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from stockcard";
        MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Clone();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the exception message that is thrown?

Comment: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

Answer (score 0):

Try `SslMode=None;`. Would be useful if you could provide the Exception thrown.

Are you sure you specified port of the MySql instance running on your server? Is it running on default port 3306?

Comment: did you try with the SslMode none?

Comment: more important, is your server online?

Comment: how do you know if it's online?

Comment: Try to start it: sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start